# Finding 9 elements with the same 'color' with weird classifier

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search

Assume i have 8 types of elements, each with a different "color", and an large "bank" array containing random elements of all types when the type is uniformly distributed.

Now, my goal is to find the fastest way to get a set of 9 elements from the same "color", but only using the following classifier:
Given an array A of n elements, return "True" if A contains a subgroup of at least 9 elements of the same "color", False otherwise.

All i can do is to organize an array by adding/removing elements and send it to the classifier, only knowledge of the "color" is that it is uniform.

As of now, I'm taking an array of size 65 from that bank. Meaning that at least one of the colors will appear 9 times (since 8*8 = 64), and checking element-by-element if removing it from the array changes the classifier answer. If the answer changes from 'True' to 'False' then the element in question is a part of a unique 'nonuplets' and should be inserted back into the array. If the answer stays 'True' than the element is simply discarded.

Is there a better way? Maybe removing 2 at a time? Some sort of binary search?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an example ?

Comment: My best example is sort of a cache miss/hit. Imagine 8 sets of a 8-way cache. 9 Lines/elements (or more) from the same set are causing some sort of a miss to the array, and i can only query a the entire array for a hit/miss.

Comment: I meant an example of input and expected output. Without that, it will be very hard for anyone to understand it clearly

Comment: The input is an infinite array, which elements are secretly colored 1-8. The output is 9 elements that have the same color. Only insight on the array is whether or not it contains at least 9 elements of the same color. My goal is to find those 9 elements with a minimal number of queries to the classifier.

Comment: So to be clear: it is not enough to get one of those 9 elements. You really need to get all 9 of them, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: The more I look into this, the more interesting this problem becomes. Thank you for the nice question! I might come back with an answer, but not any time soon though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm you currently use will call the classifier 65 times, once for every element you remove from the original array (and maybe insert back into it). So the aim is to lower that number.

### Theoretical minimum number of classifier-calls in worst case

A theoretical minimum for the worst case is 35 times:

When starting with an array of 65, it might be that there is indeed only one set of 9 elements that are of the same color, all other elements being of a different color and occurring 8 times each. In that case those 9 elements can be positioned in *C(9 of 65)* ways (ignoring order), i.e. 65!/(56!9!) = 31 966 749 880.

Since a call of the classifier has 2 possible outcomes, it divides the number of configurations that were still considered possible into two: one group is still possible, the other no longer is. The most efficient use of the classifier will aim to make that split such that 50% of the configurations is eliminated, whichever the return value (false/true).

In order to get that number of possible configurations to 1 (the final solution) you would need to perform 35 divisions by 2. Or otherwise put, 2<sup>35</sup> is the first power of 2 that is greater than that 31 billion.

So even if we would know how to use the classifier in the most optimal way, we would still need 35 calls in the worst case.

To be honest, I don't know an algorithm that would be that efficient, but with some randomness and reducing the array size with some bigger steps, you can get a better number on average than 65.

### Idea for a guessing strategy

There is approximately 50% chance that a random array of 42 objects will have 9 of the same color. You can verify this by running a large number of simulations.

So why not start with a call to the classifier with only 42 of the 65 objects you have initially picked? With a bit of luck you know after one call that your 9 objects are hidden in an array of 42 instead of 65, which would really trim the number of calls you will make in total. And if not, you just "lost" one call.

In that latter case you could try again with a new selection of 42 objects from that array. You would now certainly include the 23 other objects, as those objects would individually have a tiny bit more likelihood to be among the 9 searched elements. Maybe the classifier returns false again. That's bad luck, but you would continue using different sets of 42 until you get success. On average you will have success after 2.7 calls.

After success on an array of 42, you obviously discard the remaining 23 other objects. Now take 38 as the number of objects you will try with, following the same principle as above.

For driving the selection of the objects in each iteration, add credit to the objects that were not part of the previous selection, and sort all objects by descending credit. The added credit should be higher when the number of non-selected objects is small. Where the credit is the same, use a random order.

An additional precaution can be taken by logging all subsets for which the classifier returned false. If ever you're about to call the classifier again, first check whether it is a subset of one of those earlier made calls. If that is true, then it makes no sense to call the classifier, as it is certain it will return false. This will on average save one call to the classifier.

### Implementation

Here is a JavaScript implementation of that idea. This implementation also includes the "bank" (`get` method) and the classifier. It effectively hides the color from the algorithm.

This code will clear the job for 1000 random test cases and then output the minimum, average and maximum number of times it needed to call the classifier before finding the answer.

I used the BigInt primitive, so this will only run on JS engines that [support BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#Browser_compatibility).

```js
// This is an implementation of the bank & classifier (not part of the solution)
const {get, classify} = (function () {
    const colors = new WeakMap; // Private to this closure
    return {
        get(length) {
            return Array.from({length}, () => {
                const obj = {};
                colors.set(obj, Math.floor(Math.random()*8)); // assign random color (0..7)
                return obj; // Only return the (empty) object: its color is secret
            });
        },
        classify(arr) {
            const counts = Array(8).fill(9); // counter for 8 different colors
            return !arr.every(obj => --counts[colors.get(obj)]);
        }
    }
})();

function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
}

// Solution:
function randomReduce(get, classify) {
    // Get 65 objects from the bank, so we are sure there are 9 with the same type
    const arr = get(65); 
    // Track some extra information per object: 
    const objData = new Map(arr.map((obj, i) => [obj, { rank: 0, bit: 1n << BigInt(i) } ]));
    // Keep track of all subsets that the classifier returned false for
    const failures = [];
    let numClassifierCalls = 0;
    
    function myClassify(arr) {
        const pattern = arr.reduce((pattern, obj) => pattern | objData.get(obj).bit, 0n);
        if (failures.some(failed => (failed & pattern) === pattern)) {
            // This would be a redundant call, as we already called the classifier on a superset
            // of this array, and it returned false; so don't make the call. Just return false
            return false;
        }
        numClassifierCalls++;
        const result = classify(arr);
        if (!result) failures.push(pattern);
        return result;
    }
    
    for (let length of [42,38,35,32,29,27,25,23,21,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9]) {
        while (!myClassify(arr.slice(0, length))) {
            // Give the omited entries an increased likelihood of being seleced in the future
            let addRank = 1/(arr.length - length - 1); // Could be Infinity: then MUST use
            for (let i = length; i < arr.length; i++) {
                objData.get(arr[i]).rank += addRank;
            }
            // Randomise the array, but ensure that the most promising objects are put first
            shuffle(arr).sort((a,b) => objData.get(b).rank - objData.get(a).rank);
        }
        arr.length = length; // Discard the non-selected objects
    }
    // At this point arr.length is 9, and the classifier returned true. So we have the 9 elements.
    return numClassifierCalls; 
}

let total = 0, min = Infinity, max = 0;
let numTests = 1000;
for (let i = 0; i < numTests; i++) {
    const numClassifierCalls = randomReduce(get, classify);
    total += numClassifierCalls;
    if (numClassifierCalls < min) min = numClassifierCalls;
    if (numClassifierCalls > max) max = numClassifierCalls;
}
console.log("Number of classifier calls:");
console.log("- least: ", min);
console.log("- most: ", max);
console.log("- average: ", total/numTests);
```

### Performance statistics

The above algorithm needs an average of 35 classifier-calls to solve the problem. In the best case its calls to the classifier always return true, and then 20 calls will have been made. The downside is that the worst case is really bad and can go to 170 or more. But such cases are rare.

Here is a graph of the probability distribution:

[image]

In 99% of the cases the algorithm will find the solution in at most 50 classifier calls.

Answer (score 3):

The first step of taking 65 elements and then removing k and testing is much the same as starting with 65-k elements and then testing and adding on k if you don't have a subgroup of at least 9 of the same color. I would use e.g. Monte Carlo tests to see what the probability is of having at least 9 of the same color for each possible set of size 65-k. If this probability is p the expected number of elements in the first stage is 65-k + (1-p)k. It should be practical to make Monte Carlo tests for all possible k and see which gives you the least expected number of elements after the first test.

If you have an array of elements and test-remove each element in turn, from left to right, you should end up with 9 elements after the first pass, because each test-remove is guaranteed to work until you have only one set of 9 elements of the same color in the array, and then each test-remove works except when it removes one of the 9.

As you move along the array a test-remove is most likely to fail when there is only one set of 9 elements of the same color left, and the elements that have survived tests are of this color. Suppose you decide that you will test-remove the next element in sequence together with k other elements randomly chosen to its right. Because you know the number of elements of the set of 9 you have yet to find, you can work out the probability that this test-remove will succeed. If it fails you test just the next element. You can work out the probabilities of success and failure and find the k that removes the maximum expected number of elements in the first test, and see if this value of k is better value than just removing one element at a time.